# Trouble figuring out integer parsing function

Tags: c

I've got this function my friend did for our project:

```
int parseInt(char c) {
    return c - '0';
}
```

My friend said it turns characters into integers.

The user inputs a string with words and numbers, and we have to use the numbers in an array later so we need to turn them into integers.

But I'm having trouble understanding that bit of function and how it actually works.

Answer (score 5):

This function takes a character corresponding to one of the digits `'0'` to `'9'`.  The C standard dictates that the character codes for these digits have consecutive values.

So when `'0'`, i.e. the character code for `0` is subtracted from the given character code, you end up with a value between 0 and 9.

For example, in ASCII the codes for `'0'` to `'9'` are 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57.  So if you pass in `'4'` to this function it performs `'4' - '0'`, which is the same as `52 - 48`, which is 4.